# Como incluir na regressão uma variável elevada a n

Tags: r, lm, regressão

Suponha que eu tenha os seguintes dados

```
x<-rnorm(100,1,10000)
y<-rnorm(100,1,10000)+2*x+x^2
```

Se eu usar a função lm da seguinte maneira:

```
model1<-lm(y~x+x^2)
```

O R não entende que é para colocar entre as variáveis independentes o termo x elevado ao quadrado. Ele simplesmente ignora o termo e faz a regressão do modelo como o código abaixo:

```
model2<-lm(y~x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `model1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))`.

O problema é que caracteres como `+`, `-`, `*` e `^` possuem significados específicos dentro de uma fórmula; a função `I` faz com que a sua expressão (`x^2`) seja interpretada literalmente, como potenciação.

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra maneira de fazer a regressão é usar a função poly

```
x<-rnorm(100,1,10000)
y<-rnorm(100,1,10000)+2*x+x^2
model1<-lm(y~poly(x,degree=2,raw=T))
```

Comment: Isso! Eu lembrava que tinha uma função pra isso, mas não lembrava qual era :(

Answer (score 3):

Sempre que tu quiser utilizar uma função de alguma variável, tu pode user a função `I()`.

```
x<-rnorm(100,1,100)
y<-rnorm(100,0,10)+2*x+x^2

mod <- lm(y~x+I(x^2))
```

A vantagem de utilizar `I()` em relação a criar uma nova variável com os valores de `x^2` é que tu não precisa especificar os valores de `x^2` para realizar projeções, basta informar `x`.

```
predict(mod, data.frame(x=1:3))
        1         2         3 
 2.211883  7.209663 14.207509
```