# Data Frame e Regressão Linear

Tags: r, data.frame, regressão

Com esse data frame preciso rodar algumas regressões.
Quero fazer regressões com termos elevados a 3 e defasados.

Procurei no pacote lm e nao consegui implementar.

Quero por exemplo rodar a primeira coluna em logaritmo contra a 2ª , 3ª e a 4ª coluna ao quadrado e mais o termo defasado da primeira coluna.

```
  AnoTrimestreLAG1 ENGTrimestralemT ENGTrimestralemLAG1 CotatoTrimestralemLAG1 CotatodTrimestralLAG12
2       2014-12-31        0.7695652           0.9367866                   -1.6                  2.56
3       2014-09-30        0.9367866           1.7134771                   -0.2                  0.04
4       2014-06-30        1.7134771           2.7852691                   -0.6                  0.36
5       2014-03-31        2.7852691           2.9320260                   -1.2                  1.44
6       2013-12-31        2.9320260           3.1011732                    2.7                  7.29
7       2013-09-30        3.1011732           2.7699729                    2.1                  4.41
```

Como posso implementaar? consigo fazer uma função que faça isso? Qualquer dica ja seria o suficiente.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para fazer o `log` você pode colocar diretamente na fórmula. Exemplo:

```
# sem log
lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)

# com log
lm(log(mpg) ~ cyl, mtcars)
```

Para colocar o termo quadrático você vai utilizar a função auxiliar `I()`. Para mais detalhes ver a questão: [Como incluir na regressão uma variável elevada a n](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6237/como-incluir-na-regress%C3%A3o-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-elevada-a-n) .

Exemplo:

```
lm(mpg ~ cyl + I(cyl^2), mtcars)
```

Para colocar o `lag` é mais complicado. Você não pode usar a função `lag` diretamente. O mais adequado seria criar manualmente ou utilizar pacotes próprios para séries temporais.

Comment: Ótimo , Carlos.  Já posso partir daí,  só queria uma luz mesmo.

Comment: Contribuindo. Posso usar a função "dynlm": `Modelo1 <- dynlm(ENGTrimestralemT ~ L(CotatoTrimestralemLAG1 ,1) + L(ENGTrimestralemT , 1)-1, data = df)`
`Modelo1`